# Set value to zero if condition is fulfilled for each column separately

Tags: r, data.table

If there is an entry >= 10, I try to set all other values for that ID to zero for that specific year in a data table. All values stay the same if there is no value bigger or equal to 10. If there are more than one value bigger than 10, only the biggest entry should be kept.

Here I have a sample data table:

```
library(data.table)

data = data.table(
  ID = c("a1", "a2", "a2", "a1", "a2", "a1", "a1"),
  "2018" = c(3,5,11,3,9,22,6),
  "2019" = c(3,5,6,21,1,4,0),
  "2020" = c(0,4,13,9,16,7,9),
  "2021" = c(4,0,3,8,5,4,6))
```

I tried it with a for loop, but I wasn't able to do it with two dimensions.
The desired outcome would look like that:

```
solution <- data.table(
  ID = c("a1", "a2", "a2", "a1", "a2", "a1", "a1"),
  "2018" = c(0,0,11,0,0,22,0),
  "2019" = c(0,5,6,21,1,0,0),
  "2020" = c(0,0,0,9,16,7,9),
  "2021" = c(4,0,3,8,5,4,6))
```

Comment: Is it grouped by 'ID'

Comment: No not necessary, thanks a lot for your answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- names(data)[-1]
data[, (nm1) := lapply(.SD, function(x) if(any(x >= 10)) 
       replace(x, x != max(x), 0) else x), ID]
```

-output

```
> data
   ID 2018 2019 2020 2021
1: a1    0    0    0    4
2: a2    0    5    0    0
3: a2   11    6    0    3
4: a1    0   21    9    8
5: a2    0    1   16    5
6: a1   22    0    7    4
7: a1    0    0    9    6
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept a solution with `tibble` instead of `data.table`,

```r
library(tidyverse)

data = tibble(
  ID = c("a1", "a2", "a2", "a1", "a2", "a1", "a1"),
  "2018" = c(3,5,11,3,9,22,6),
  "2019" = c(3,5,6,21,1,4,0),
  "2020" = c(0,4,13,9,16,7,9),
  "2021" = c(4,0,3,8,5,4,6))

data %>% 
  mutate(row_id = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(row_id, ID), names_to = "year") %>%
  group_by(year, ID) %>%
  mutate(
    value = if (any(value >= 10)) {
      if_else(1:length(value) == which.max(value), value, 0)
    } else {
      value
    }) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 6
#>   ID    row_id `2018` `2019` `2020` `2021`
#>   <chr>  <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 a1         1      0      0      0      4
#> 2 a2         2      0      5      0      0
#> 3 a2         3     11      6      0      3
#> 4 a1         4      0     21      9      8
#> 5 a2         5      0      1     16      5
#> 6 a1         6     22      0      7      4
#> 7 a1         7      0      0      9      6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Great thanks a lot, in my case data.table works better